# What problems can I have with a background thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, background-thread

I have an application that needs to execute a code in background. I just created an empty background task and a thread. In theory this thread should be suspended after 10 minutes, but I saw that it was still alive. What problems can be generated rather than performance?

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    }];

     NSThread * thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(execute:) object:nil];
     [thread start];
}


-(id) execute: (id) obj{
    while (true) {
        NSLog(@"My thread %f", [myApplication backgroundTimeRemaining]);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return nil;
}
```

PS there is no UIBackgroundModes set on the plist

Comment: all I can say is only update UI on main thread

Comment: Ok, but rather than that what can happen for example if you have to download some data from internet and store it into the database?

Comment: Never had any problems with that, just do everything on your background thread but whenever you need to update your UI, do it on the main one